# Git revert files to point of branch creation (No Commit)

Tags: git

Heres the scenario:

Developer forgets to create a new branch and makes changes to master. The developer then does...

`git checkout -b newbranch
git stash
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout newbranch
git merge master`

All changes from the command of `git checkout -b newbranch` are lost. Is there a way to recover those changes at the moment the developer created newbranch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be "lost" (not really) if those changes were not added/committed.

But at least those local modification were stashed: a `git stash apply` should restore them (after the final `git merge master`).

By precaution, I would do a `git stash apply` instead of `git stash pop`, in order to see if those changes are indeed applied, before dropping them from the stash.